# Can I Use Google App Engine as XMPP Gateway

Tags: google-app-engine, azure, amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd

I have a Cloud App hosted on Windows Azure and I need to integrate XMPP with the service. Can I use GAE's XMPP API to achieve this? I'll need to be able to create new Jabber IDs and send & receive messages from other clients like GTalk.

As far as I know, GAE only supports Java, Python and my expertise is limited to .NET & C#; so, I'll have to make my Azure App to communicate with the GAE.

Finally, can I use GAE as an alternative to running `ejabbered` on `Windows Azure Virtual Machines or Amazon EC2`?

Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could but it would be very limited.  You may be better off running ejabbered somewhere else.

- With GAE's XMPP API, your username selection is rather limited.  See the GAE XMPP Overview API documentation.
- Your Cloud App would need to send and receive messages from your GAE app via HTTP accesses.  This is no big deal for sending, but you'll have to work your own way of receiving messages.  You could buffer your messages to the datstore and poll for messages.  You could use the Channel API to receive messages directly, but so far the Channel API client is only available in Javascript, so your app would need some sort of javascript interpreter to use the client.
- You will be able to send/receive messages from other XMPP addresses like GTalk clients.

Comment: Okay... that makes sense... Could you please tell me that, is EJabbered is the best XMPP Server to go forward or is there anything better? like OpenFire? Also which platform(OS) should I select? Is there any advantage for Linux over Windows in this context? My App is built using .NET only.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure that out with a bit of Googling.